# What is LINK rel=subresource used for?

Tags: javascript, html

What is **link rel="subresource"** used for?
What difference would that make if I use **link rel="subresource"** instead of link **rel="text/javascript"** for including .JS files?

Answer (score 12):

Chrome is going to remove `<link rel=subresource>` because it is not useful, proprietary, and buggy.

See https://crbug.com/581840

Removed in Chrome 50 https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6596598008119296

Use `<link rel=preload>` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

Answer (score 10):

As of 2016 the `subresource` value for the `rel` attribute was [deprecated and removed](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/Y_2eFRh9BOs/gULYapoRBwAJ).

It has been superseded by the [Preload API](http://w3c.github.io/preload/) instead, meaning one should do `rel=preload` for a similar effect. To quote the specs

> The `preload` keyword on link elements provides a declarative fetch
>   primitive that initiates an early fetch and separates fetching from
>   resource execution.
>
> As such, the `preload` keyword serves as a low-level primitive that enables
>   applications to build custom resource loading and execution behaviors
>   without hiding resources from the user agent and incurring delayed
>   resource fetching penalties.
>
> For example, the application can use the `preload` keyword to initiate
>   early, high-priority, and non-render-blocking fetch of a CSS resource
>   that can then be applied by the application at appropriate time.

---

Below is the  original answer written in 2015, for posterity, that explains the then valid `subresource` keyword.

---

The `rel=subresource` link is what is called Link prefetching, where the browser tries to fetch the resource before it's needed, so it can load that resource faster from cache when it is in fact needed later on.

[Link prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) is a browser mechanism to download or prefetch resources.

> Link prefetching is a browser mechanism, which utilizes browser idle
>   time to download or prefetch documents that the user might visit in
>   the near future. A web page provides a set of prefetching hints to the
>   browser, and after the browser is finished loading the page, it begins
>   silently prefetching specified documents and stores them in its cache.
>   When the user visits one of the prefetched documents, it can be served
>   up quickly out of the browser's cache.

The server provides hints to the browser and the browser can consult its cache and take action based on these hints.

The existing link prefetching uses a standard HTTP link header, and defines semantics for the link relation type "prefetch".

`link rel=subresource` provides a new link relation type with different semantics from `link rel=prefetch`.

While `rel=prefetch` provides a low-priority download of resources to be used on subsequent pages, `rel=subresource` ***enables early loading of resources within the current page***.  Because the resource is intended for use within the current page, it must be loaded at high priority in order to be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still have some doubt about the 2nd part. If I use **link rel="subresource"** rather than the more common **link rel="Styelsheet"** will that help render javascript files faster comparitively?

Comment: Not neccessarely, it would probably be slower in some cases as it would wait for the browser to be idle before loading the stylesheet. As for using the `subresource` value, that would in most cases load the stylesheet just as it would if the value was `stylesheet` if the resource was needed on pageload, so it wouldn't generally be any faster. Prefecthing is most useful when you want to load a resource that is needed on the next visited page, or by something in the same page later on, say by triggering an event etc.

Comment: so using `subresource` on current page resources actually make them load ASYNC and not be blocking? I find the explanation difficult to understand. Why would I ever need to use `subresource`? what is an example use case? obviously if I want things to be loaded ASAP I'll put them in the HEAD element, but normally you would put Scripts before the `</body>` closing tag, so they will be loaded last, and not block anything, so you don't need any `rel=subresource` for them.. And is it only for actual files? if will put a URL which points to some other page, what would be downloaded?

Comment: Can I assume that scripts loaded this way will only be loaded, and not executed until the regular request?